# Test multiple repos in travis ci

Tags: github, travis-ci

So I have many related, but different git repositories. All of which have their own isolated testing.  But a few have cross-dependancies (e.g. Mozilla's "buildbotcustom" and "buildbot-configs" repositories depend on one another for our deployment).

Our old jenkins UX performed an integration test whenever any of the related repositories changed.

I have mentally looked at travis-ping and git submodule support (tracking a branch rather than an indivual commit) for doing these types of testing, however the former needs a user/password combo that is prompted for, and the latter doesn't look like it will trigger tests when its submodules are pushed to, only when the encompassing project is pushed to.

Is there a way to trigger either another github repo's travis run when pushing to another repo? *or* is there a way to have a repo's submodules also trigger travis-ci jobs?

If there are other solutions/approaches to this issue I'm happy to hear them.

Comment: To say it, if we were to redesign existing systems we wouldn't have divergent repos like this that depend on one another. Or at least not without some submodule support up front. But it is what we have, and process debt prevents a change in the near future.  This question is aimed at eliminating one aspect of our process debt so we can continue to flow forward into new areas faster.

Comment: We want to evaluate travis-ci to and to do so, we also need to figure out something to address our dependent builds.
This article is the best answer i found so far: http://eng.rightscale.com/2015/04/27/dependent-builds-in-travis.html